# How do you search for unicode strings?

Tags: ida

In all versions of IDA, I can't seem to be able to search for unicode strings. When reversing programs, I constantly see unicode strings that could have really helped if I could see them in the strings window, but I can't. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Enter the "strings window" by either press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> or go to `View > Open Subviews > Strings` in the toolbar.

Then, in the strings window, press Right Click and choose "Setup...". Check "Unicode" and press "OK".

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this until now, thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a registry change during this selection `HKCU\Software\Hex-Rays\StrWinStringTypes -- REG_BINARY -- 00 01 02`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!